# Trying to find a novel/story I read online a few years ago

Tags: story-identification, magic

So I'm trying to remember a story I read some years ago, can't remember how long ago. I am fairly certain the Main Characters name is Mikhail(or so minor spelling variation on it), who is born into a family that runs a magic school that is on a island with very high walls to protect it from the tide. He is one of the rare male mages and quite powerful at that. Makes a staff and sword out of hyper compressed stone and then enchants them, they are used as gifts for two sisters, princess if I recall right, as they graduate the school his family runs. When he leaves the island to go to a school and hides the fact he can use magic he gets a companion named crystal. He also founds a company called Hearthstone enterprises(90% sure this is the name they use) with one of the sisters to fund himself by selling his enchanted stone gear.

That's about all I can remember about the story. Thanks for any help in advance.